# Calculate $P (X < 3)$

Tags: probability

One box contains $10$ balls numbered from $1$ to $10$. $4$ balls are removed from this box with replacement. Let $X$ and $Y$ respectively be the minimum and maximum number of balls withdrawn. Calculate $P (X < 3)$, ie the probability that none of the numbers is greater than $2$.

I would like to understand why doing $0,2^4$ is incorrect. The answer is $1−0.8^4$.

Comment: Not clear ... 'spare' balls are removed'? ... numbers of balls 'served'? ... please explain what is happening here a little more ... maybe give an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your incorrect answer, $0.2^4$, represents the probability that all four balls removed from the box (with replacement) are all less than $3$. For example, this counts results like $(1, 1, 2, 1)$ and $(2, 1, 1, 2)$.

Instead, we want to find the probability that at least one of the four balls removed from the box (with replacement) is less than $3$. For example, this counts results like $(8, 2, 6, 6)$ and $(3, 1, 1, 9)$. To do this, we find the opposite of what we want (all four balls are greater than or equal to $3$), then subtract this from $1$. This yields:
$$
1 - (0.8)^4
$$